# Job for uwsgi.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to deploy my django app using nginx and uWSGI. 
However I cannot start uWSGI on emperor mode. 
If I `sudo systemctl start uwsgi`
Then fails saying

```
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-01-09 08:15:01 JST; 1min 47s ago
  Process: 23295 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown nginx:nginx /run/uwsgi (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

my  /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service is

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown nginx:nginx /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/home/me/.venv/uwsgi/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?